# Is There A Feature To Display Only Live Questions?

Tags: support, feature-request

At any given time, a significant subset of questions displayed are closed, on hold, duplicates, moved, etc.

Is there any choice for displaying questions that suppresses these questions and instead displays only the questions that remain live for discussion?

If not, consider this a feature request for such an option.

Comment: Related: [Can I filter/hide closed questions on Programmers.SE?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2802/can-i-filter-hide-closed-questions-on-programmers-se)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the search operators defined in Advanced Search Tips:

[image]

---

**For Politics SE, simply use this link - https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3a0%20duplicate%3a0%20migrated%3a0.**

- closed:0 [not closed]
- duplicate:0 [not duplicate]
- migrated:0 [not migrated]
- sort by newest